# Java Change Swing Components after expiry of a time

Tags: java, swing

i have a graphical user interface with some images. after i press 
a button, i change this images and repaint the whole graphical user
interface. This works very fine.

To show you what i do here a small visualisation. i have 8 Images:

```
1. 2. 3. 4.
5. 6. 7. 8.
```

After i press the button all immages rotate the steps to the left:

```
2. 3. 4. 8.
1. 5. 6. 7. 

3. 4. 8. 7.
2. 1. 5. 6. 

4. 8. 7. 6.
3. 2. 1. 5.
```

Ok here we are. As i already have mentioned this works fine!
After each single step i repaint the graphical user interface
but ofcourse this happens so fast, that you dont see the steps
between start and end. you just see the origin:

```
1. 2. 3. 4. 
5. 6. 7. 8.
```

And the last transformation

```
4. 8. 7. 6. 
3. 2. 1. 5.
```

But Actually i want the user to see each single step. So 
i thought i can just add a Thread.sleep() after each Step
but this freezes the graphical user interface (something
with the Event Dispatcher Thread i found out)

So i tried to put everything into this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        changeGUI();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

But with it nothing changes. It still goes very fast i 
just see the origin and the last transformation.

The method who calls the repainting of all my swing components
is called 'changeGUI()'

So how can i actually implement the functionallity to repaint
after a certain amount of time?

- origin
- wait a sec
- first transformation
- wait a sec
- ....

Answer (score 4):

What you are going to want to use is the [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Sleeping on the swing thread causes freezing issues, which is what you are doing.

Example:

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
...
final Timer print = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("It's been 1 second!");
        }
});
print.start();
```

Comment: I think this worked but i cant say now because i get a java.lang.StackOverflowError. I think i have to tell my programm to wait until all timers are finished but i actually dont know how to do it.

Comment: You only have to use one timer. You can restart an timer and at least you can stop it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start a new Thread which invokes changeGUI().

invokeLater don´t have an effect because when you call it e.g. in a button-event,
you already are on the EDT. And then you add the changeGUI()-call to the EDT, too.

Build your own Thread or use an ThreadPoolExecutor to start another thread to invoke
changeGUI();

Answer (score 0):

Would be possible you share the code of your method "changeGUI()"?
But have in mind that all drawing and UI updates should be made through the EDT (Event-Dispatch Thread). Take a look at this [article](http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0812/zarra/index.html). You'll find a very useful explanation about swing, thread and events.